# Weird Shading while rendering

Tags: rendering, camera, lighting, shadows

I have this weird shadow on my coins while rendering. It does not appear in any other case than rendering. I tried rotating my light but it doesn't help. And I think it's not the topology causing the problem. If I move my camera the shadow moves with it. How do I fix the issue?
[image]

Comment: Hello what weird shadow? Maybe you have an object thas us hidden for preview but enabled for render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was caused by incorrect normals. So recalculating normals outside made the shadow disappear. I also cleaned up my topology even more but that's just to be safe.